# How to upgrade the version of Groovy used by the extensible choice parameter plugin

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I need to access the [parallel collections](http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/dataParallelism.html), but the bundled Groovy is quite old: version 1.8.9.  The current version of Groovy is 2.4.

Is there a plugin in Jenkins, that can fill a combo parameter and allows to use a newer version of Groovy?.

I know the bundled version by using `GroovySystem.getVersion()`.

I've tried to install the [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin), which allows to use any Groovy version, but doesn't affect the parameter plugins like [Extended Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin).

Comment: Jenkins 2.x has Groovy version 2.4.7 bundled in.